# Running Air Application on a Server

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a client/server application, where the client side is written in Flex/Air, and the server side in Scala.

The client side uses a local SQLite database that I would like to generate on the server side (it is small, so it can be retrieved via http when needed).

The frequency of updates is low: more or less one per day. The complication is that the database uses the Air extensions to SQLite, so it has to be generated by an Air application.

I have thought of two possible approaches:

1. Write a small server program in Air, and trigger it from my Scala application via
   sockets. Data would be passed to the Air application in the http body.
2. Execute the Air server program from the Scala application whenever I need the updates to be made. Data would be passed via a file (I don't think an Air application can read stdin).

I am more inclined for the second option, since it would require less admin work (no need to check if the Air side of the server is up). However, I am not sure about the ability of Air to run as a "console" application (I don't like the cumbersome idea of creating a temporary file to pass data).

Has anybody had a similar problem before?

Comment: Actually it's not a requirement that AIR initially create the db, so long as it conforms to a SQLite pragma spec, any editor/creator can also do this if needed. 

Why not just have the client AIR app check your server if it has the latest version? If not, download - and merge via sql import statements, or something similar.

Comment: @MikePetty: that is what I am doing now, and it is very difficult to keep the versions in sync. Since it is a small database, I'd rather download the whole thing. I have columns of type Object, which I think are not standard in SQLite but rather an Air extension.