# calling swf function from java (without loading swf file into browser)

Tags: java, javascript, apache-flex, flex3, flash

I searched a lot regarding this topic but did not get any good answer.

Scenario:
We have Rest web service bases implementation in our project. Ideally frontEnd (Flex) call web service and backend send huge data point to frontEnd. Then frontEnd create chart of these data points and display to end user.

Our requirement is that user can export these charts and save as pdf file  on the server. We are able to create JPG file from flex server and save as pdf file.

Problem occurs when end user has scheduled that chart report. Now that report can run at any time and may be browser is not opened at that time. So how backEnd will interact with frontEnd (flex) functions. Problems are:

1. browser is not opened so swf file is not loaded.
2. java/jsp need to interact with frontEnd(flex) as a reverseAjax so that frontEnd send JPG file back to server.

Does anybody face this issue before?
Is it somehow possible??

Asnwers/any leads are highly appreciated. 
Please provide comments on this

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to do this is to run a version of your Flex application (at least the charting part) on your server, and have your Java server interact with it.

I have faced a similar problem and have [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813492/running-air-application-on-a-server) a similar question before. It is not very elegant, but what I mentioned before seems to be the only way to go.

Comment: Edurado, can you please help me to find out how to deploy flex application on the server so that we can access it outside server without using browser.